# What is the best practice when designing an interface methods that operate on single or many values

Tags: php

What is the best practice when designing an interface methods that operate on single or many values.

Do I design interface like this:

```
interface DbItf
{
   /**
    * Drop table.
    *
    * @param string $tableName The database table name.
    *
    * @return bool Returns true on success, false on failure.
    */
    public function dbDropTable($tableName);

   /**
    * Drop tables.
    *
    * @param string[] $tableName The list of database table names.
    *
    * @return bool Returns true on success, false if one or more operations failed.
    */
    public function dbDropTables(array $tableName);

}
```

or:

```
interface DbItf
{
   /**
    * Drop table or tables.
    *
    * @param string|string[] $tableName The table name or list table names.
    *
    * @return bool Returns true on success, false if one or more operations failed.
    */
    public function dbDropTable($tableName);

}
```

What are pros and cons of creating interfaces using the first or second approach?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely an opinion as best practices often are.

I think the first example is redundant.  As long as you have it documented that it accepts a string and an array, then the second example would be fine, although potentially confusing as many may think just by the name that it only accepts one table.  Changing the name to `dropTables` may make more sense if you want it to accept multiple values.

Note I also removed the `db` prefix.  You are already in the `Db` interface, having `db` in the method is redundant in my opinion.